# Abrir projeto existente Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-4, laravel-5.3

Preciso abrir um projeto anteriormente feito em laravel.

Nunca trabalhei com laravel, por este motivo não sei onde posso estar errando.

o projeto veio em um arquivo .zip 
quando descompactei ele criou uma pasta chamada engraf182-meu-projeto-6609a7d53557

dentro desta pasta tem os arquivos

bootstrap,
node_modules,
public,
storage e
vendor

pelo que olhei de laravel esta não é a forma que o laravel cria suas pastas em um novo projeto.

cada pasta dessas tem mais um punhado de pastas dentro e arquivos criptografados.

alguém pode me ajudar a abrir este projeto??

Obrigado

Comment: E ficheiros na root? Tens certo?

Answer (score 6):

Seu computador precisará ter o PHP e essas extensões (a depender da versão do Laravel da sua aplicação, veja a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5#server-requirements)):

- Relacionar o item
- PHP >= 7.0.0
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension

Você também vai precisar rodar o comando `composer update` na pasta raiz do projeto. Para isso terá que instalar o Composer caso ainda não tenha instalado (veja o [tutorial do site oficial](https://getcomposer.org/download/)).

Depois disso, basta rodar `php artisan serve` na raiz do projeto. Abra o site http://localhost:8080, e você verá o projeto.

Resumindo:

1. Instalar o PHP e extensões do Laravel
2. Instalar o Composer
3. Baixar as dependências do projeto usando `composer update`
4. Rodar `php artisan serve`

* Se seu projeto utilizar banco de dados, você precisará instalar o banco de dados e rodar `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score -2):

Olá, depois de muito apanhar com projetos Laravel, faço da seguinte forma:

Após descompactar o projeto ou clonar por git, pegue o arquivo .env.example e apenas renomeio ele para .env caso este projeto utilize banco de dados mysql, sugiro que crie primeiramente com SQLITE para ver se vai funcionar, então abra o arquivo renomeado .env e neste trecho:

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=laravel

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=

deixe somente esta linha e remova as outras 5 linhas abaixo até DB_PASSWORD, ficando desta forma:

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite

O Laravel para funcionar algo que foi recente clonado ou descompactado precisa rodar o comando (não sei porque em termos técnicos) No terminal na pasta raiz você roda:
-- php artisan key:generate

Provavel, que de erro, algor como este erro "PHP Warning:  require /autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in \artisan on line 18" ou algo do genero. Certo, ai é só fazer os comandos abaixo:

-- npm install

-- npm audit fix

-- composer update

-- php artisan migrate

Pronto, após algumas exceptions ao rodar o comando, é só executar:

-- php artisan serve

Espero ter ajudado.